# How to create android homescreen layout

Tags: android, layout

How to achieve this kind of layout? i am new to android. can you help me please? thanks. i will mark this as answer after for those who can answer.thanks a lot.!

[image: image link]
<sub>(source: [tnwcdn.com](http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/files/2011/04/2.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) you can understand how to create buttons with image and text, I'm not going to make the app for you, don't be lazy and search more before asking something like this.